# Como insertar un producto a mi usuario

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Tengo dos tablas :

**Tabla producto**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ProductoSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    descripcion:{type:String, require:false},
    precio:{type:Number, required:false},
    fecha_lanzamiento:{type:String, required:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto',ProductoSchema);
```

**Tabla Usuario**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    apellidos:{type:String, required:false},
    usuario:{type:String, required:false},
    email:{type:String, required:false},
    password:{type:String, required:false},
    fecha_registro:{type:String, required:false},
    carrito:[
             { 
                type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Carrito",
                cantidad:{type:Number,required:true}
            }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario',UsuarioSchema);
```

Mi **usuario.controller.js** es el siguiente:

```
const Usuario = require('../models/usuario');
const Producto = require('../models/producto');

const usuarioCtrl = {};


usuarioCtrl.getUsers = async (req, res) => {
   const usuarios = await Usuario.find();
   res.json(usuarios);
}

usuarioCtrl.getUser = async (req,res)=>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    const usuario = await Usuario.findById(id);
    res.json(usuario);
}

usuarioCtrl.createUser = async (req,res)=>{
   const usuario = new  Usuario(req.body);
   await usuario.save();

   res.json('Empleado guardado');
}

usuarioCtrl.editUser = (req,res)=>{
  const {id} = req.params;

  const usuario = {
    nombre:req.body.nombre,
    apellidos:req.body.apellidos,
    usuario:req.body.usuario,
    email:req.body.email,
    password:req.body.password,
    fecha_registro:req.body.fecha_registro
  }

  Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set:usuario}, {new:true});
  res.json({
      status:'Usuario actualizado'
  });
}

usuarioCtrl.deleteUser =async (req,res)=>{
    let id = req.params.id;
    await Usuario.findByIdAndRemove(id);

    res.json({
        status: 'Usuario eliminado'
    });

}

usuarioCtrl.addProductoToCarrito = async(req,res)=>{
  let id_producto = req.params.id;
  let producto = await Producto.findById(id_producto);
}

module.exports = usuarioCtrl;
```

Justamente la última función de mi **controlador** debe de guardarme el `array` de productos dentro de la tabla usuario, el producto y su cantidad.

¿Como debería de hacer mi controlador correctamente ?

```
usuarioCtrl.addProductoToCarrito = async(req,res)=>{
  let id_producto = req.params.id;
  let producto = await Producto.findById(id_producto);
}
```

Como se puede ver, eso es lo que estoy intentando pero una vez tengo el `id` del producto ¿necesitaría el `id` del usuario que también se lo paso por la **url**? Es decir para añadir ese producto al usuario.

Answer (score 4):

Lo primero que vamos a hacer es dejar de llamar ***tablas*** a las **colecciones** de MongoDB, son cosas totalmente diferentes. Además, tampoco llamaremos ***filas*** o ***registros*** a los **documentos**. Y por supuesto en MongDB no existe tal cosa llamada ***columna***, y mucho menos se habla de ***relación***, sólo se habla de **referencia**.

En cuanto a tu pregunta: ***¿Como debería de hacer mi controlador correctamente ?***

La verdad es que **NO** deberías poner la lógica de transacción comercial dentro del controlador de usuario. El controlador de usuario debería ser exclusivamente para realizar operaciones [CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) sobre los documentos tipo usuario y sobre las propiedades de dichos documentos únicamente.

Las propiedades de un usuario las defines de acuerdo a tus requerimientos, pero las mismas normalmente tienden a reflejar las características de un modelo de la vida real.

Supongamos que tu modelo de usuario está pensado para asemejarse a la tarjeta de membresía o de cliente de tu comercio o negocio. Los datos que deben aparecer reflejados en dicha tarjeta deberían ser los que vamos a modelar para nuestro documento de usuario. Por lo tanto, no tiene sentido o no es correcto añadir un campo donde se almacene un producto de compra. Eso no es parte de la tarjeta de cliente.

Por otra parte, el manejo del *carrito* de compras deberías hacerlo desde el lado de frontend, ya que no tiene sentido práctico enviar una petición `http` al servidor para añadir un producto al carrito, otra petición para eliminar un producto del carrito y otra petición para mostrar los productos que hay en el carrito.

Volvemos a las semejanzas, imagina que en supermercado, cada vez que vas a agregar un producto al carrito debes pasar por la caja de pago, y luego para sacar algún producto debes volver a pasar por la caja de pago, y si necesitas ver todo lo que llevas en el carrito debes volver a pasar por la caja de pago. ¿Tiene sentido hacer las cosas así?

Lo que envías al servidor debería ser una solicitud de pedido, con los productos que hay actualmente en el carrito listos para ser procesados por el servidor y generar una transacción de venta.

Dicho esto, vamos a ver una forma en la que podrías crear un modelo de pedido de productos, y cómo relacionar esto con documentos de tu colección de usuarios y documentos de tu colección de productos.

En tu pregunta surge una duda: ***¿necesitaría el id del usuario que también se lo paso por la url?***

La verdad es que deberías poder manejar la sesión de usuario usando algún sistema de token como [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken), o de `cookies`, o tal vez algo un poco más complejo como `OAuth`. De esta forma, con cada petición de un usuario logueado, la información de identificación del mismo debería estar disponible sin necesidad de realizar una verificación previa (llámese consulta a BD). Esa es la esencia de las sesiones de usuario. ¿Imaginas que al iniciar sesión en Windows o Linux o Mac OS, tuvieras que introducir tu usuario y clave por cada programa, tarea o ventana a ejecutar? Nada productivo eso.

Nuestro modelo lo crearemos mediante la definición de un esquema de Mongoose, tal como has creado tus modelos de Usuario y de Productos. Este modelo lo vamos a crear lo más simple posible.

**pedido.model.js**

```
// Usaremos ES5
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const PedidoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'usuarios',
        required: 'Campo id usuario es requerido'
    },
    productos: [{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'productos',
            required: 'Campo id producto es requerido.'
        },
        cantidad: {
            type: Number,
            default: 1
        }
    }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Pedido', PedidoSchema);
```

Con esto ya tenemos el modelo de nuestro pedido de compras muy básico.

Ahora debemos definir el controlador, esto es algo más complejo, y dependerá de tus reglas de negocio.

Vamos a definir un controlador para manejar las órdenes o pedidos, y entre los métodos que tendrá este controlador crearemos el de *realizar pedido*. Este método simplemente grabará la información del pedido en un documento en la colección de pedidos y devolverá el resultado de dicho proceso, para continuar luego hacia algún proceso de solicitud de pago.

Dado que no has definido cómo manejas la sesión de usuario, voy a agregar un middleware que se encargue de verificar si el pedido es realizado por un usuario logueado o no. Este middleware no lo vamos a escribir en esta respuesta, ya que no es parte de la pregunta, pero en todo caso el mismo debería poder identificar si el usuario ha realizado login y si la sesión es aún válida o activa. Si se cumplen las condiciones necesarias, el middleware debe devolverme el `id` del usuario que realiza el pedido, en caso contrario debería redirigir al cliente a la página de login, manteniendo los datos del pedido.

**ordenes.controller.js**

```
const Pedido = require('/ruta/a/pedido.model');

const generarPedido = (req, res, next) => {
    //asumiré que el id del producto a añadir viene en el cuerpo (body) de la solicitud
    //además el id del usuario viene en un campo llamado profile en el request
    const productos = req.body.productos;
    const userId = req.profile.userId;
    const pedido = new Pedido({customer: userId, productos: productos});
    pedido.save((err, pedidoResultante)  => {
        if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: `Error al generar pedido: ${err.message}`
            });
        }
        req.pedido = pedidoResultante;
        next();
    });
}

module.exports = { generarPedido }
```

Nuestra función generar pedido realiza una sola tarea: guardar un pedido en la base de datos. Y así debería ser con cada método de nuestros controladores. Esto se conoce como la [filosofía Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well): *Hacer una sola cosa y hacerla bien*.

Por último está el tema de las rutas y los middleware que se pasarán al router. La decisión sobre las ruta o endpoint para acceder a tu API es algo que se ajustará a los requerimientos de tu aplicación. No sé cómo manejas la estructura de rutas, asi que colocaré algo muy básico para darte una idea.

**router.js**

```
const authCtrl = require('/ruta/a/auth.controller');
const orderCtrl = require('/ruta/a/ordernes.controller');
const router = require('express').Router();
//manejamos la ruta para procesar un pedido
router.route('/shop/order/submit')
    .post(authCtrl.requireLogin,orderCtrl.generarPedido, ... );

module.exports = router;
```

De esta forma ya podemos generar un documento de pedido en nuestra base de datos. Cada documento de pedido tiene una referencia al usuario que realizó el pedido y a los productos, además tiene la cantidad de productos.

Al grabar el pedido en la base de datos se genera un identificador único de pedido y además, por defecto (si no se han cambiado la opciones) se agregan los campos `createdAt` y `updatedAt`, que sirven de referencia para temas de reporte.

Al grabar el pedido en la base de datos, el resultado devuelto es el documento generado (que ahora posee un `id` único), el cual se almacena en el objeto `req` bajo el nombre de `pedido`. En nuestro controlador, el método `generarPedido` llama a la función `next()`, lo cual hace que el siguiente middleware en la cadena de ejecución sea llamado y así continuar hacia un proceso de pago o finalización de pedido, eso ya lo decides según los requerimientos que tenga tu aplicación.

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas.