# Problema al usar logica en un middleware y pasarle los datos al siguiente middleware [Reestructurado]

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Teniendo el siguiente **json**:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
      "nombre":"Paraguas",
      "descripcion":"Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
      "precio":500,
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
      "nombre":"Paraguas",
      "descripcion":"Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
      "precio":500,
      "__v":0
   },
   {
      "_id":"5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
      "nombre":"Paraguas",
      "descripcion":"Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
      "precio":500,
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

Quiero **evitar que se repita el mismo json en el array** y que se cree una propiedad en el json llamada **cantidad**. SI es la primera vez que se inserta ese producto que lo inserte con **cantidad : 1** si es la segunda que **no repita todo el json**, simplemente **aumente +1 la propiedad cantidad**.

Decir que la **cantidad** la crea el middleware en el schema **no existe** ese atributo.

El flujo de mi backend en express es el siguiente:

Yo accedo a mi **URI** = `http://localhost:3000/api/usuario/{usuario._id}/{producto._id}`

entonces imaginemos que tenemos este **usuario**:

```
[
    {
        "carrito": [],
        "_id": "5cf7f921e101b4166c7b305d",
        "nombre": "jose",
        "apellidos": "rodriguez",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

ahora este usuario quiere guardar en su cesta un **producto**, en este caso :

```
   {
      "_id":"5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
      "nombre":"Paraguas",
      "descripcion":"Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
      "precio":500,
      "__v":0
   }
```

Reocordando la **URI** que se encarga de hacer todo esto (`http://localhost:3000/api/usuario/{usuario._id}/{producto._id}`) recibe **2 parametros** como se puede observar.

Recordad tambien que estamos en un controlador de **express**.

Antes de continuar dejo mi modelo de **usuario** y **producto**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    apellidos:{type:String, required:false},
    usuario:{type:String, required:false},
    email:{type:String, required:false},
    password:{type:String, required:false},
    fecha_registro:{type:String, required:false},
    carrito:[]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Usuario',UsuarioSchema);






const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const ProductoSchema = new Schema({
    nombre:{type:String, required:true},
    descripcion:{type:String, require:false},
    precio:{type:Number, required:false},
    fecha_lanzamiento:{type:String, required:false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Producto',ProductoSchema);
```

Ahora vayamos a los controladores de mi backend, en concreto a mi **usuario.controller.js**

esta es la funcion que llama mi **URI**:

```
usuarioCtrl.addProductoToCarrito = async(req,res)=>{
  let id_usuario = req.params.id_usuario;
  let id_producto = req.params.id_producto;


  let producto = await Producto.findById(id_producto);
  let usuario = await Usuario.findById(id_usuario);

  let productoReworked = req.productoReworked;



  usuario.carrito.push(productoReworked);
  usuario.save();


  res.json({
    usuario: usuario,
    producto:producto
  })

}
```

Pero ANTES de llamar a la dicha funcion llama a un **MIDDLEWARE** que **organizara** un poco el carrito.

Dicho **middleware** es el que expongo a continuacion:

```
usuarioCtrl.checkAddProduct = async (req, res, next) => {

  let id_usuario = req.params.id_usuario;
  let id_producto = req.params.id_producto;

  let producto = await Producto.findById(id_producto);
  let usuario = await Usuario.findById(id_usuario);

  let carrito = usuario.carrito;

  console.log(carrito);

  let exist = carrito.find(obj => obj._id == id_producto);
  console.log("EXISTE PRODUCTO = " + exist);

  if (exist == undefined) {
    console.log("NO EXISTE")
    producto["cantidad"] = 1;
  }
  else {
    console.log("SI EXISTE")
   producto.cantidad = producto.cantidad + 1;

  }

  res.productoReworked = usuario.carrito;
  next();



}
```

Este middleware **hara ciertas comprobaciones**. Dira si el producto ya esta metido en el carrito y hara dos **modificaciones al json fundamentales**

**SI NO EXISTE AUN EN EL CARRITO DICHO PRODUCTO =** creara un atributo nuevo a mi json de `Usuario` llamado `cantidad` y tendra el valor de `1`.

**SI EXISTE EN EL CARRITO DICHO PRODUCTO =** **sumara +1** a la propiedad `cantidad`

Una vez hecha las modificaciones oportunas quiero que el middleware envie los datos modificados(con el campo cantidad y su valor correspondiente segun exista ya o no el producto en la cesta) al **controlador** que se encargara de guardar los datos.

En el **controlador siguiente** tenemos :

```
  usuarioCtrl.addProductoToCarrito = async (req, res) => {
      let id_usuario = req.params.id_usuario;
      let id_producto = req.params.id_producto;


      let producto = await Producto.findById(id_producto);
      let usuario = await Usuario.findById(id_usuario);

      let productoReworked = req.productoReworked;



      usuario.carrito.push(productoReworked);
      usuario.save();


      res.json({
        usuario: usuario,
        producto: producto
      })

    }
```

Simplemente **obtiene el nuevo carrito por parametro** y modifica el que recibe de serie. Y finalmente lo guarda.

**El PROBLEMA** esta en que en vez de insertar :

```
       {
        "usuario": {
            "carrito": [
              {
              "_id":"5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
              "nombre":"Paraguas",
              "descripcion":"Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
              "precio":500,
              "__v":0,
              "cantidad":X
           }
            ]
    }

}
```

Me inserta un nulo:

```
  {
                "_id": "5cf7bc1cce902c37b8208dfc",
                "nombre": "Paraguas",
                "descripcion": "Con este producto no te vas a mojar la cabeza",
                "precio": 500,
                "__v": 0
            },
            null,
```

Comment: Estas usando javascript?

Comment: estoy en node, asi que si es js

Comment: Bueno ya indique que estuve probando con include como dice la docu para busquedas de array de javascript.

Comment: Voy a editar la pregunta.

Comment: La pregunta ha sido eitada y extensamente comentada. Espero que todo este bastante mas claro

Comment: Por que en vez de utlizar `async` y `await` no utilizas promesas?

Comment: Porque como consultas que peuden tardar un rato le pongo eso para que este seguro que las traiga

Comment: Es un poco mas claro usar promesas. Te recomiendo que investigues sobre ellas. Estas tratando de agregar una propiedad a un modelo de mongoose y eso no se puede hacer. Por eso te da nulo. Cuando haces la llamada dentro del middleware lo que obtienes no es un json en si, es un objeto de mongoose.

Comment: Prueba agregando al final `Producto.findById(id_producto).lean()`

Comment: Entonces como puedo hacer para cuando inserte 2 productos iguales no los replicque si no diga que hay 2 ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94557/discussion-between-angel-and-josanangel).

Comment: Hola, entiendo todo el enredo que tienes. Podrías darle un vistazo a [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269756/como-insertar-un-producto-a-mi-usuario/269930#269930) respuesta que quizás te haga ver las cosas un poco diferentes a cómo te las estás planteando. Saludos

Comment: Hola, leyendo tu código con detenimiento tienes un error. En tu middleware donde verificas si el producto ya existe en el `array`, haces: `res.productoReworked = usuario.carrito;`, pero luego en el siguiente middleware haces: `let productoReworked = req.productoReworked;`. El objeto `res` es diferente del objeto `req`, te aconsejo que cambies por: `req.productoReworked = usuario.carrito;` (usando `req`) ya que es el objeto que deberíamos manipular siempre entre middlewares. Saludos